# How to use "clearInterval" in a different if statement to the "setInterval"

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js, setinterval, clearinterval

I've tried searching for other examples, to fix this issue by myself but I'm fairly new to coding in general and I'm very new to java script so I apologise in advance for any silly mistakes I make.

Basically, I am learning javascript and I thought that a good interactive way of learning would be to make a discord bot so I can "see" my effort paying off and therefore keep up my motivation. I decided a basic spam bot would be a good starting point to get me familiar with the most basic aspects.

After some research I found the method "[setInterval](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval)" which seemed perfect for the application I had in mind. This method will execute a line of code every given time interval.

So I can get my bot to spam a discord channel just fine, but this issue im having is if I want to get it to stop.

```
client.on('message', message => {           //reacting when ever the 'message' EVENT occurs (e.g. a message is sent on a text channel in discord)

console.log('A message was detected and this is my reaction');
console.log(message.author + ' also knows as ' + message.author.username + ' said:\t' + message.content);       //message.author is the value of the person who sent the message, message.content is the content of the message


if(message.author.bot) {
    return null                 //returns nothing if the message author is the bot


} else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}spam`)) {
    
    let timerId = setInterval(() => {                                           //starts to spams the channel
        message.channel.send('spamtest');
    }, 1500);   


} else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}stop`)) {

    clearInterval(timerId);
    message.channel.send('condition met');

}
```

});

The error I get here is that timerId is not defined. So I thought thats because its a local variable, and now im stumped. I dont know what else to try and ive been getting quite frustrated over something this simple, so I was hoping that someone here could help.

Thanks

Comment: `let` is block scoped ... and you're using it in two separate blocks - try declaring `let timerId` just above the first `if`

Comment: @JaromandaX is right. That is going to work. You can't access `timerId` outside of the if block

Comment: Yea thanks guys/girls i'm cringing at how dumb I was now :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by [Jaromanda X in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63299480/how-to-use-clearinterval-in-a-different-if-statement-to-the-setinterval-ja#comment111931702_63299480), the [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) keyword declares a variable in the current block scope, making the variable inaccessible to the other block scope (the other `else if` block).

To fix this, you need to declare the variable `timerId` in the global scope, so that it is accessible by all other block scopes:

```js
let timerId; // declare timer in global scope

client.on('message', message => {           //reacting when ever the 'message' EVENT occurs (e.g. a message is sent on a text channel in discord)

console.log('A message was detected and this is my reaction');
console.log(message.author + ' also knows as ' + message.author.username + ' said:\t' + message.content);       //message.author is the value of the person who sent the message, message.content is the content of the message


if(message.author.bot) {
    return null                 //returns nothing if the message author is the bot


} else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}spam`)) {
    
    timerId = setInterval(() => {                                           //starts to spams the channel
        message.channel.send('spamtest');
    }, 1500);   


} else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}stop`)) {

    clearInterval(timerId);
    message.channel.send('condition met');

}
```